# Theorems (or references to analysis) of a particular Hilbert-deductive-system using $\\{\neg, \wedge, \vee, \rightarrow\\}$ as primitive symbols?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms, hilbert-calculus

## Context

### The System `CL`

In section 6.3 of *Topoi*, Robert Goldblatt describes a Hilbert-style deductive calculus (the only inference law is [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens)) for the propositional logic of a language with the primitive logical connective symbols $\\{\neg, \wedge, \vee, \rightarrow\\}$, which he calls `CL`, with following axiom schemata:

1. $\alpha\rightarrow(\alpha\wedge\alpha)$
2. $(\alpha\wedge\beta)\rightarrow(\beta\wedge\alpha)$
3. $(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow((\alpha\wedge\gamma)\rightarrow(\beta\wedge\gamma))$
4. $((\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\wedge(\beta\rightarrow\gamma))\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)$
5. $\beta\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$
6. $(\alpha\wedge(\alpha\rightarrow\beta))\rightarrow\beta$
7. $\alpha\rightarrow(\alpha\vee\beta)$
8. $(\alpha\vee\beta)\rightarrow(\beta\vee\alpha)$
9. $((\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)\wedge(\beta\rightarrow\gamma))\rightarrow((\alpha\vee\beta)\rightarrow\gamma))$
10. $\neg\alpha\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$
11. $((\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\wedge(\alpha\rightarrow\neg\beta))\rightarrow\neg\alpha$
12. $\alpha\vee\neg\alpha$

### Some Thoughts

Goldblatt claims that the theorems of this system are the tautologies of classical propositional logic.  However, these axioms are different from the ones I'm used to seeing, such as [Łukasiewicz's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms), where in particular $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are *defined*, rather than *primitive*, connectives.  (I will refer to this system as `HS`.)  Moreover, Goldblatt doesn't provide any examples of this axiom system *in action*, so it's hard for me to see how it would actually prove simple tautologies, like $(A\wedge A)\rightarrow A$ or $A\rightarrow A$.

## Questions

I'm looking for *any of the following* to help me better understand `CL`'s "engine", so to speak (by analogy with `HS`, see [some proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Some_useful_theorems_and_their_proofs) or [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Logic)):

- Does anybody have a reference to an analysis of (the propositional fragment of) a Hilbert system with a similar set of axioms--in particular, one with the same set of primitive logical connectives?
- How does a formal proof of $A \rightarrow A$ (or, better yet, $(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))$, an axiom of `HS`), look like in `CL`?
- How can I prove the conjunction [introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction)/[elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) laws as metatheorems using `CL`?  If I knew how to do this, then I think I could probably figure out how to prove the deduction theorem.
- How would I prove the remaining laws of inference of natural deduction, in particular disjunctive [elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination)/[syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism), as metatheorems using `CL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, not a very intuitive system.  But I agree, the key is probably to figure out Conjunction Introduction and Conjunction Elimination and from there you can probably get to the Deduction Theorem.

Ok, I found Conjunction Introduction:

$1. \alpha$

$2. \beta$

$3. \alpha \land \alpha (1, Ax. 1)$

$4. \alpha \to \beta (2, Ax.5)$

$5. \beta \land \alpha (3,4.Ax.3)$

Comment: (5.) is a bit abbreviated.  This actually clears it up for me a lot, thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderSanchez Yeah, went a bit quick but I figured you could piece it together from there :P … still trying to figure out conjunction elimination …

Comment: @AlexanderSanchez  No luck figuring out how to do Conjunction Elimination. I'm stumped :(

Comment: No worries.  You found conjugation introduction super quick--which has already been super helpful to me.  Conjugation elimination is probably buried under a handful of tough tricks.